# PHP Login validation with XML

Tags: php, html, xml, authentication, xml-parsing

Every time I login it goes to shop.php page. I am confused where I'm doing wrong. Anyone here to figure that out for me? Thanks

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("info.xml");
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $user=$_POST["username"];
     $pass=$_POST["password"];
     $account=$_POST["accounttype"];

     foreach ($xml->author as $author) {
         if ($user==$author->aName && $pass==$author->apassword && 
 $account==$author->$author->{"Buyer"}) {
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $user;
             $_SESSION['pass_login'] = $pass;
             header("location:shop.php");
             exit();
         } elseif ($user==$author->aName && $pass==$author->apassword && 
  $account==$author->$author->{"Seller"}) {
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $user;
             $_SESSION['pass_login'] = $pass;
             header("location:admin.php");
             exit();
         } else {
             $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>
  <strong>Invalid credentials. Try again!</div>';
         }
     }
 }
?>
```

My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authorList>
    <author>
        <aName>bbb</aName>
        <apassword>bbb</apassword>
        <aemail>email@yahoo.com</aemail>
        <aphone>111</aphone>
        <aaccounttype>Buyer</aaccounttype>
    </author>
    <author>
        <aName>sss</aName>
        <apassword>sss</apassword>
        <aemail>test@yahoo.com</aemail>
        <aphone>222</aphone>
        <aaccounttype>Seller</aaccounttype>
    </author>
</authorList>
```

Comment: `$author->$author->{"Buyer"}`. Are you sure that's correct? And how is `$author` defined?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, here is the xml code-

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authorList>
  <author>
    <aName>bbb</aName>
    <apassword>bbb</apassword>
    <aemail>email@yahoo.com</aemail>
    <aphone>111</aphone>
    <aaccounttype>Buyer</aaccounttype>
  </author>
  <author>
    <aName>sss</aName>
    <apassword>sss</apassword>
    <aemail>test@yahoo.com</aemail>
    <aphone>222</aphone>
    <aaccounttype>Seller</aaccounttype>
  </author>
</authorList>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be checking that the passed in account type matches the one on the record, you just need to check the value from the XML file is either Buyer or Seller...

```
if ($user==$author->aName && $pass==$author->apassword &&
        $author->aaccounttype == "Seller" ) {
```

or

```
if ($user==$author->aName && $pass==$author->apassword &&
        $author->aaccounttype == "Buyer" ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should simply need to change your two `if` conditionals:

```
if (... $account == $author->$author->{"Buyer"})
if (... $account == $author->$author->{"Seller"})
```

Should become:

```
if (... $account == $author->aaccounttype)
if (... $account == $author->aaccounttype)
```

And your `$_POST` variable `accounttype` should map out to `Buyer` and `Seller` respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working :( What I want is to redirect to shop.php if the account type is Buyer and admin.php if the account type is Seller. And in XML its like this <aaccounttype>Seller</aaccounttype>